# Unity - Rotate an object around a point in 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

I've been working on a 2D game in Unity and I need to find a way to rotate a sprite around a certain point. I know that for 3D games, Unity has a built in `transform.RotateAround()` function but I'm not sure how to achieve the 2D equivalent. If anybody can help, a response would be much appreciated.

Comment: um why can't you use the `transform.RotateAround()` function for 2d?

Comment: you can use the same function. the Axis of rotation will simply become Vector3.back or Vector3.forward depending on the direction you want to rotate.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to use the function in 2D ryeMoss. I didn't think it could be used for 2D as I tried to use it before and my character just rotated on the spot. I have just tried it again though, with the way you explained how to use it, and it now works! Thanks again!

Comment: You could use a pivot point too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same function. `transform.RotateAround()` takes a `Vector3 point`, a `Vector3 axis`, and a `float angle` in degrees.

the point and angle are pretty self explanitory, but the axis is a little less so. This is essentially the direction of rotation. In a default Unity2D game where z is your depth (into the screen), you'll want to rotate around the Z axis: `new Vector3(0,0,1)` or `Vector3.forward`.

try something like:

```
Vector3 point = new Vector3(5,0,0);
Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0,0,1);
transform.RotateAround(point, axis, Time.deltaTime * 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are struggling to get your head around these transformation functions, there is an alternative way to do it. Simple create a new gameobject at the point you wish to rotate around. Then make the sprite a child of that game object. When you rotate the game object the sprite should move about that point.

Comment: I know this thread is old BUT this is an excellent answer!:)

Answer (score 2):

actually you can use some GameObject as anchor:

```
    public GameObject anchor;
    public float velocidad;
    void Start () {
        velocidad = 50f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        transform.RotateAround(anchor.transform.localPosition, Vector3.back, Time.deltaTime*velocidad);
    }
```